# android cannot find symbol com.google.android.gms.wallet build errors

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-pay

I am trying to install https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe in my android react native project and am having a few errors during build around google wallet.

I have tried the support thread of the github repo but to no avail and I am getting to the stage where I really need this integrated.

It seems like it cannot find the wallet SDK for some reason and im not sure why.

Here are gists that document both my build gradle and the errors that I am getting during build:
https://gist.github.com/danwoodbury/69f75393e747f3781b2c5338c9c59c1b

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the dependency `com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:16.0.0` would be declared in the `build.gradle` ...while it might not be available locally. try to run `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` in the project directory. and make sure Gradle is not in offline mode.

could build it; with build-tools `3.1.4` and Gradle `4.4` (wrapper).

Comment: thanks for the pointer i got to new stage. it passes that section so thanks for that. but... i now get a different error right at the end of the build `com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list`. this feels never ending

Comment: @danwoodbury impossible to tell without a stack-trace. https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1051 ...hints for updating Play Services, which current is at `4.1.0`.

Comment: thanks. I had previously found that thread but unfortunately it didnt helpe me. I have updated my gist at https://gist.github.com/danwoodbury/69f75393e747f3781b2c5338c9c59c1b and provided the stacktrace